# jpa association children entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have an entity Person which is parent of two other entities: Caller and Employee. These entities are implemented using SINGE_TABLE strategy with a discriminator column : person_id.
Also i have another entity: Location which has a ManyToMany relation with Person. So, a person may belong to multiple locations and a location can have multiple persons.
It was easy to map Location and Person with manyToMany, but now i need a way to map children entities, because in location i need some methods like: getEmployees(); and getCallers();
i tried something like :

```
public class Location implements Serializable, Comparable<Location> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="locations")
    private List<Caller> callers = new ArrayList<Caller>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="locations")
    private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("0")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)   

public class Caller extends Person {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name = "company_name")
private String companyName;

@Column(name = "individual")
private Boolean individual;
}

@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class Employee extends Person {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526471155622776147L;

}

@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="person_type",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@Table(name="persons")
public class Person implements Serializable, Comparable<Person>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526471155622776147L;


    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="persons_locations",
               joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="person_id")},
               inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="location_id")})
    private List<Location> locations;
}
```

but i get this error when i try to compile the app:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: xxx.entities.yyy.Caller.locations in xxx.vs.entities.yyy.Location.callers.
```

I guess that one solution would to move the locations down into children, but then i`ll have to copy/paste some code, after all Location is a property of a generic person.

what is the proper way to deal with this kind of issue ?

Answer (score 0):

What you tried won't work. If you have an association between Caller and Location, the association must be defined in Caller, not in Person. Same for Employee. And I *think* you'll need two different join tables, as well.

Comment: hmm.. so basically i have to duplicate location property  in both employee and caller classes...

Comment: That's it. I would avoid using the same name in both classes, though, because you'll have problems in queries if you do that.

Comment: this will be not so nice, because i have multiple relationships that i was hoping to map to this person in order to avoid exactly that kind of problems :(